# How to add include paths for JS Modules

Tags: javascript, module, google-closure-compiler

How to specify which directories Closure Compiler should search in when importing JavaScript modules like this:

```
import foo from 'components/A'
import foo from 'third_party/B'
require('library/C')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure-compiler doesn't "search" for modules. You must pass the appropriate source files in via the `--js` flag or the source files methods of the gulp/grunt plugins. Closure-compiler does resolve relative path modules - but they will be resolved from the source file import location. The compiler does not currently resolve imports from node_modules folders.